# Titanium mobile Alloy: fraction view size in *.tss or *.xml

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have container with seven views inside:

```
<View class="container>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
</View>
```

Is it possible to set width of buttons to 1/7 of container width in *.tss or *.xml without using postlayout event? With four views I can simply specify `25%`, but with `14.285714285%` for seven sum of view width become more then 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it becomes more than 100% is because [floating point math is funky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/874257). Also, to compound this I think Titanium rounds those percentages in code (just speculation).

For simplicity, try and keep the percentages to whole numbers, like this:

```
".day" : {
    width : "14%"
}

<View class="container" layout="horizontal">
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
    <Button class="day"/>
</View>
```

You might be able to get away with "14.2%" as well, since it does not have so many significant digits.

Comment: This solution will not work correctly. Depends on width of the parent it may cause pixel misalignment and it will not fill up whole view's width.

Comment: @0101 The point of the question was that the views size depend on the width of the parent. This works well enough, and fills 99.4% of the container.

Comment: If you think that this is good enough then OK... but sorry I can't agree with you.

Comment: What would you suggest then?

Comment: I would like to post my solution ,but I can't untill I don't have all details from @farwayer

Comment: Thx for responses guys. @JosiahHester I know about float number peculiarity. @0101 I'm using horizontal layout and want buttons fill all container size. I set `horizontalWrap: false` to prevent last button go to next line. All ok before using `borderColor`. In this situation right border of last button is missing. For now I see two workarounds: calculate and set last button width less than others in `postlayout` event or create fake view at right edge of container with back color similar to `borderColor`. But it's kludge.

Comment: What about size of `.container`? Is it fixed size? e.g. `.container {width: 300, height: 50}`. Is it for iOS & Android?